Synchronous VS setting by reference
I have some trouble with my function, which:

set product And price in stripe
Then set my postRequest with return of stripe ( product_id and price_id )
Get my collection product  (subscription ) on my DB (firestore)
Push my postRequest in collection
And update collecttion

My probleme : process Stripe is always ok BUT sometime my collection is not update with product_id and stripe_id
I thinks I have use await everywhere to be full synchronous.
But I have always this random problem.
My function
const createSubscription = async(req, res, next) => {

  try{

    // const userToken = req.header('Authorization')
    // const userId = await userService.verifyUserToken(req, userToken)
    // await userService.verifyAdmin(req, userId)
    await stripeService.initStripe(req)

    //if itt's not a free offer : manage product and price in side stripe
    //then set body data with product_id and list_price
    if(await !req.body.isFree){
      const product = await stripeService.createProduct({data : req.body})


      if ( await product.id) {

        const allPriceForProduct = await setAllPriceProduct(product.id, req)

        delete req.body.stripe_list_prices

        req.body.stripe_product_id = product.id
        req.body.stripe_list_prices = [...allPriceForProduct]
        console.log('here')

      } else {
        throw new Error('No product idd');
      }

    }

console.log(req.body)
    //Get and set collection subscription
    const subscriptionDB = await subscriptionService.getRefAndDataSubscription(req);
    await subscriptionDB.data.options.push(req.body)
console.log(subscriptionDB.data)

    await subscriptionService.updateSubscriptionRef(req, subscriptionDB.ref, subscriptionDB.data )


    const subscriptionData = await subscriptionService.getRefAndDataSubscription(req);


    res.json(subscriptionData.data.options)

  }catch (e){
    console.error('stripe_error_create_offer', e.message)
    //send mail admin + log admin ????
    res.status(500)
  }

  next()

}

You will notice that result of my console.log(), req.body and subscriptionDB.data just before update of collection are ALWAYS good. The price_id and product_id are setting with response of stripe, but sometimes collection is update WITHOUT product_id and price_id.
It's like function who update collection is played before the real update of object subscriptionDB.data, but all is synchronous with await.
What's wrong?
I thinks that timeout resolve problem, but is that a good practice?
I expect an update of my collection with and object updated in 100% of time.
